# Google sheets: find value multiple times from column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, indexing, match

I have a list of city names (col 2). If the city name exists in another list (Col 1), I would like to match this city name and write the URL (Col 3).

I have tried with index match, regex match, search with wildcard but have not found a solution.

How do I do it?

regexmatch(to_text(A2:A), textjoin("|", 1, to_text(B2:B))),C2:C,"no city"
This just writes TRUE or FALSE but does not look up the URL (Col 3)

Col 1                   Col 2          Col 3 (URL)       col 4 (result)
Philadelphia clothing   Chicago        Chicago URL       Philadelphia URL
Chicago                 Philadelphia   Philadelphia URL  Chicago URL
outerwear
Philadelphia shoes                                       Philadelphia URL

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(z,IF(z="",,XLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(z,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,B2:B))),B:B,C:C,))))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Wow, it works! This is absolutely fantastic, thank you very much for the help